# Postfix + Courier + MySql mail server with SASL

Tags: email, postfix, sasl, courier

I am really at a loss configuring this mail-server deployment.  I am following the excellent guide posted at http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/.  I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on Linode.

While following the guide to the letter I encountered an error from Postfix when sending outgoing from Thunderbird Mail Client.

`warning: SASL authentication failure: no secret in database`

Which was followed by a generic authentication failure message.

After some googling, I found the following in the Postfix documentation that seems to countervail the Flurdy guide:

> If you must store encrypted passwords, you cannot use the ldapdb
>   auxprop plugin. Instead, you can use "saslauthd -a ldap" to query the
>   LDAP database directly, with appropriate configuration in
>   saslauthd.conf. This may be documented in a later version of this
>   document. You will not be able to use any of the methods that require
>   access to plaintext passwords, such as the shared-secret methods
>   CRAM-MD5 and DIGEST-MD5.

The guide seems to rely on PAM to circumvent this limitation, but I think this is the leg of my configuration that was not working (the no secret in database error.)  I removed the CRAM-MD5 and DIGEST-MD5 mechanisms from my /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf, and now I can login using PLAIN.

**The problem is that these passwords are now being transmitted unencrypted.  There is also a strange problem where our Thunderbird clients can't seem to save messages to the "Sent" folder and just hang on the sending progress bar after transmission is complete.**

I would like to move on to configuring TLS to make the connection more secure, but so far this has been such a nightmare I'm almost afraid to go further and risk breaking the config.  I'm not at all familiar with a lot of these services and would love a point in the right direction.

Configuration:

`/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf`

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login 
log_level: 7
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: mail
sql_passw: *redacted*
sql_database: maildb
sql_select: select crypt from users where id='%u@%r' and enabled = 1
```

`/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

myhostname = mail.hostname_here.com
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
myorigin = gonation.com

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

relayhost = 
mynetworks_style = host
local_recipient_maps = 
mydestination = 

# how long if undelivered before sending warning update to sender       
delay_warning_time = 4h 
# will it be a permanent error or temporary
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450 
# how long to keep message on queue before return as failed.
# some have 3 days, I have 16 days as I am backup server for some people
# whom go on holiday with their server switched off.
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d 
# max and min time in seconds between retries if connection failed
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s 
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s 
# how long to wait when servers connect before receiving rest of data
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s 
# how many address can be used in one message.
# effective stopper to mass spammers, accidental copy in whole address list
# but may restrict intentional mail shots.
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16 
# how many error before back off.
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3 
# how many max errors before blocking it.
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12

# Requirements for the HELO statement
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname,reject_invalid_hostname,permit
# Requirements for the connecting server 
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl,reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org 
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

# require proper helo at connections 
smtpd_helo_required = yes
# waste spammers time before rejecting them
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# not sure of the difference of the next two
# but they are needed for local aliasing
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
# this specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
# this is for the mailbox location for each user
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
# and this is for aliases
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
# and this is for domain lookups
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
# this is how to connect to the domains (all virtual, but the option is there)
# not used yet
# transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_transport.cf

virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

# SASL
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# If your potential clients use Outlook Express or other older clients
# this needs to be set to yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl2_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =

smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks,warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_unauth_pipelining,permit

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
```

`/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

`/etc/pam.d/smtp`

```
auth required pam_mysql.so user=mail passwd=*redacted* host=127.0.0.1 db=maildb table=users usercolumn=id passwdcolumn=crypt crypt=1
account sufficient pam_mysql.so user=mail passwd=*redacted* host=127.0.0.1 db=maildb table=users usercolumn=id passwdcolumn=crypt crypt=1
```

`/etc/default/saslauthd`

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="pam"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-r -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

Comment: I managed to get the Thunderbird folder addressing to work properly by changing the IMAP server directory to "INBOX" and the personal namespace to "INBOX."  The settings are located under the "server settings" for the mail account in the "Advanced" dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting SASL to work is the most difficult thing. Anyways you got that to work. Go ahead follow flurdy's part to enable TLS, that part is not going to break anything for you. The snakeoil files are already there so there is no need for generating the ssl files.

Comment: Is there any vulnerability to be considered with just leaving the password as PLAIN login if I use TLS, since it will be communicated through an encrypted tunnel anyway?  I just got TLS for outgoing working.

Comment: I dont think so. TLS will give you end to end encryption. So you dont have to worry much.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I now have everything up and running.